# REST API: When should we use different HTTP status code other than popular ones?

Tags: rest, api, http, http-status-codes

We have API that returns back customer details i.e. /api/customers/{customerid}/. We have following scenario:

1. If passed customerid is non-integer OR <=0 OR greater than Maximum(customerid) in our database, we send back BadRequest i.e. HTTP status code 400.
2. If the request to this API comes from any IP that we have blocked, we send back HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden).
3. If customerid is deleted: We send back 404.

I was thinking why do we really need to think and have all these different HTTP status codes? All we need here is to show an appropriate message on the client which we can easily do by returning HTTP status code 400 for all above cases and just have different string message for all above 3 cases.

This would work in my case but I was wondering when would we inevitably need these special status codes other 200, 400 and 500?

Comment: When I use REST APIs, I base a lot of what I do on the status code, so if I got a 404, I would know that there is no customer and move on, but if I got a 403, I would look to see why I couldn't access that user. A standard 400 for everything would make it harder to troubleshoot issues.

Comment: but android/ios/web clients simply needs to display message in this case, why would we return special status code for these?

Comment: @Loaf True. I can't count all the times `418` saved me hours of  troubleshooting ;)

Comment: @jonahe Saves me time to make tea in my little teapot

Comment: Note that in your scenario 1, the appropriate status code is `404`. A resource was requested that doesn't exist. The fact that your API requires integers in that part of the uri is just an implementation detail of your API. In scenario 3, a nicer status code might be `410`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when would we inevitably need these special status codes other 200, 400 and 500?

The point of using the more specialized codes is that it allows generic clients (like web browsers) and intermediate components (caches) to act intelligently; they can do this because the status codes (like the meta data in the header fields) have standardized definitions.

[401 Unauthorized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) is a straightforward example of this - your server tells the browser that some identifying credentials are required, and the browser knows that it can repeat the request with identifying information provided by the user.

It's not *wrong* to use 200/400/500 everywhere; doing so misses an opportunity for intermediaries to participate more fully in the message exchange.

It's analogous to using POST for every request: you *can* do it, but in doing so you give up the [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)/[idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) semantics; without those hints, you limit how much help the intermediate components can provide when the communication goes off the happy path.